# Bing search: Exact sentence with quotation marks

Tags: google-search, search-engines, bing

I using Bing.com for searching some text in the internet. In most of cases, I using this search query:

> "This is my exact text"

This working as expected. Additionally, sometimes, I need to search an expresion with quotation marks. E.g. this text:

> Albert Einstein said: "The only source of knowledge is experience".

Now, just adding " before and after the sentence will break the query:

> "Albert Einstein said: "The only source of knowledge is experience"."

The last query gives me bad results.

How to do this right?
Same question, for Google search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using single quotes around the text he said instead of double, don't forget your dot is also separate at the moment.